# When using Jeffrey's prior for Normal model, what is $p_J(\theta, \sigma^{2} | y_{1}, ..., y_{n})$ supposed to be?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior, jeffreys-prior, unit-information-prior

I'm reading [A First Course in Bayesian Statistical Methods by P. Hoff](http://www.stat.washington.edu/people/pdhoff/book.php) where he is using Jeffrey's prior (J) and Unit information prior (U) for Normal model. For example we can derive Jeffrey's prior for Normal model and get $p_{J}(\theta, \sigma^2) = (\sigma^2)^{-3/2}$ and then obtain a posterior $p(\theta, \sigma^2 | y_{1}, ..., y_{n})$ as the product of prior and likelihood. I don't understand what he means by probability density with subscript J, for example: $p_{J}(\theta, \sigma^{2} | y_{1}, ..., y_{n})$ or $p_{J}(\theta | \sigma^2, y_{1}, ..., y_{n})$. Can someone please explain?

Comment: In the context of the problem, it means the posterior pdf associated with Jeffrey's prior. i.e. it is $p_J(\theta,\sigma^2|y_1,...,y_n)\propto p_J(\theta,\sigma^2)p(y_1,...,y_n|\theta,\sigma^2)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so it is only the posterior we obtain as the product of Jeffrey's prior and likelihood? And what is $p_{J}(\theta | \sigma^2, y_{1}, ..., y_{n})$ and $p_{J}(\sigma^2 | y_{1}, ..., y_{n})$ supposed to be and how to derive it?

Comment: In general the posterior is the product of the prior and the likelihood. The subscript J is only to indicate that in the particular example the Jeffrey's prior is used. Consequently the $p_{J}(\theta|\ldots)$ and $p_{J}(\sigma^2|\ldots)$ are the full conditional for the parameters $\theta,\sigma^2$ which are obtained from the full posterior under the Jeffreys prior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the posterior is the product of the prior and the likelihood. The subscript J is only to indicate that in the particular example the Jeffrey's prior is used. Consequently the

$p_{J}(\theta|\ldots)$ and $p_{J}(\sigma^2|\ldots)$

are the full conditional for the parameters $\theta,\sigma^2$ which are obtained from the full posterior under the Jeffreys prior. You derive them from the full posterior as the distribution depending only on the parameter of interest up to a constant of proportionality.

For example suppose that we have a posterior of the form

$ p(\mu,\lambda|\ldots) \propto \lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}(x-\mu)^2}.$

Then the full conditional for $\lambda$ is

$p(\lambda|\ldots) \propto \lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}(x-\mu)^2},$ which is a $Ga\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2\right),$

and for $\mu$

$p(\mu|\ldots) \propto e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}(x-\mu)^2},$ which after some
algebra is a normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now. For my example, Normal model with Jeffrey's prior, I derived full conditionals $p_{J}(\theta | \sigma^{2}, y_{1}, ..., y_{n}) \propto \texttt{Normal}(\bar{y}, \sigma^2/n)$ and $p_{J}(\sigma^{2} | y_{1}, ..., y_{n}) \propto \texttt{InverseGamma}(n/2, \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - \bar{y})^{2}/2)$.

Comment: No problem at all. I am glad i helped!